# Implementing matching pursuit algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sparse-matrix

I have implemented *matching pursuit* algorithm but i m unable to get the required result.

**Here is my code:**

```
D=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
    2 7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
    3 8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
    4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
    5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50];
b=[6;7;8;9;10];
n=size(D);
A1=zeros(n);
R=b;
H=10;
if(H <= 0)
    error('The number of iterations needs to be greater then 0')
end;
for k=1:1:H
    [c,d] = max(abs(D'*R));    %//'
    A1(:,d)=D(:,d);
    D(:,d)=0;
    y = A1\b;
    R = b-A1*y;
end
```

**Output**

```
y=

0.8889  
     0  
     0  
     0  
     0  
     0  
     0  
     0  
     0  
0.1111
```

I should get only non-zero value at `(2,1)` and other values should be zero but I'm getting 2 non-zero value. Can you please help me find out where the error is?

Thanks.

Comment: When I run your code, I get all zeros except for (2,1)....

Comment: @RobertStettler i get non-zero value at (1,1) and (10,1),can you tell where is the error?

Comment: Two things come to mind: What version of MATLAB are you using? Do a `clear all` before running this script

Comment: @RobertStettler i am using matlab10

Comment: Moreover: I get an `rank deficient` warning, is it possible, that your code is wrong? e.g.  lines `y=A1\b` and `R=b-A1*y` make no sense, since `A1*y=b` for a general case but due to rank deficiency it is not... I'm not familiar with the matching pursuit algorithm

Comment: @RobertStettler i get the same warning.

Comment: I think the code is wrong. R is all zero at the end and A1 is weirdly populated. The lines I mentioned before make no sense and are mathematically not clean. Try to review your algorithm.

Comment: @RobertStettler I m providing you the link of matching pursuit algorithm,please help me,i m trying from a lot  .[link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit)

Answer (score 1):

I checked with:
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Matching_pursuit

Your functions need to be normalized!

```
D = D./repmat(sum(D,1),5,1);
```

I get the following algorithm:

```
D=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
    2 7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
    3 8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
    4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
    5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50];
D = D./repmat(sum(D,1),5,1);
b=[6;7;8;9;10];
n=size(D);
A1=zeros(n);
R=b;
H=100;
if(H <= 0)
    error('The number of iterations needs to be greater then 0')
end;
a = zeros(1,H);
G = zeros(size(D,1),H);
for k=1:1:H
    ip = D'*R;
    [~,d] = max(abs(ip));    %//'
    G(:,k) = D(:,d);
    a(k) = ip(d);
    R = R-a(k)*G(:,k);
end

% recover signal:
Rrec = zeros(size(R));
for i=1:H
    Rrec = Rrec + a(i)*G(:,i);
end
figure();
plot(b);
hold on;
plot(Rrec)
```

It approximates the signal quite well. But not with D(:,2) at first as expected. Maybe it is a starting point...

Comment: i don't get the requried output,please see the matching pursuit algorithm as i m providing.[link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit)

Comment: Do you know how to modify the code for orthogonal matching pursuit?

Comment: @Steffen This code works well for **b=[6;7;8;9;10]** but what if the signal is changed to some random value such as **b=[100;20;200;150;10]**. It doesn't work. Any comment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code. This is based on the algorithm provided at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit

```
clc;
clear all;

D=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
    2 7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
    3 8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
    4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
    5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50];

b=[6;7;8;9;10];

H=10;

for index=1:10
   G(:,index)=D(:,index)./norm(D(:,index)); 
end
G1=G;

n=size(G);
R=b;
if(H <= 0)
    error('The number of iterations needs to be greater then 0')
end;
if(H >size(D,2))
    error('The number of iterations needs to be less than dictionary size')
end;

bIndex=1:size(G,2);
for k=H:-1:1
    innerProduct=[];
    for index=1:size(G,2)
        innerProduct(index)=dot(R,G(:,index));
    end
    [c,d] = max(abs(innerProduct));    
    An(H-k+1)=innerProduct(d);
    R = R-(An(H-k+1)*G(:,d));
    G(:,d)=[];
    strong(H-k+1)=bIndex(d);
    bIndex(d)=[];
end
G_new=G1(:,strong);


%% reconstruction
bReconstructed=zeros(size(G_new,1),1);
for index=1:size(G_new,2)
    bReconstructed(:,index) = (An(index)*G_new(:,index));
end
b_new=sum(bReconstructed,2)
```

Comment: Do you know how to modify the code for orthogonal matching pursuit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the atoms in the dictionary must be normalized so that the inner products of the current residual with different atoms can be compared fairly.

You may want to check my OMP implementation which also includes incremental Cholesky updates for the least square step in OMP at https://github.com/indigits/sparse-plex/blob/master/library/%2Bspx/%2Bpursuit/%2Bsingle/omp_chol.m

I have written detailed tutorial notes on OMP in my library documentation at https://sparse-plex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/pursuit/omp/index.html

My library sparse-plex contains a C implementation of OMP which is close to 4 times faster than fastest MATLAB implementations.  See the discussion here https://sparse-plex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/pursuit/omp/fast_omp.html